# How to delete item from viewpager and pageradapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using pageradapter and viewpager to display imageview array,textview array .But how do I delete pager on button click .Entire code in the code below ,but I have added button in xml onclick should delete the page.

https://www.swipetips.com/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

```
 package com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        String[] rank;
        String[] country;
        String[] population;
        int[] flag;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
                String[] population, int[] flag) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rank = rank;
            this.country = country;
            this.population = population;
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rank.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {

            // Declare Variables
            TextView txtrank;
            TextView txtcountry;
            TextView txtpopulation;
            ImageView imgflag;

            Button b;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                    false);

            // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
            txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
            b=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);


            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                }
            });

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
            txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
            txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);

            // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
            imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            // Capture position and set to the ImageView
            imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
    }
```

////////////////////

```
// Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country, population, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

first you need to use `List` because of dynamically deleting objects.
second you need

```
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

to force the adapter to create new page each time and not using in memory pages.

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    List<String> rank;
    List<String> country;
    List<String> population;
    List<Integer> flag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
            String[] population, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rank = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(rank));
        this.country = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(country));
        this.population = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(population));
        for (int i : flag){ 
            this.flag.add(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rank.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtrank;
        TextView txtcountry;
        TextView txtpopulation;
        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
        txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
         Button b=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

         final int delPosition = position;

         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 rank.remove(delPosition);
                 country.remove(delPosition);
                 population.remove(delPosition);
                 flag.remove(delPosition);
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
         });
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtrank.setText(rank.get(position));
        txtcountry.setText(country.get(position));
        txtpopulation.setText(population.get(position));

        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag.get(position));

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, my app crashes when I try to delete the last item of my list. It says, "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6". It points to this line: imageView.setImageResource(regionImages.get(position));

Comment: @KalaJ post your code as a question on the SO. then tell me the link!

Comment: actually, I have a new viewpager question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632219/how-can-i-save-the-state-and-value-of-button-press-between-views-in-a-viewpager Can you take a look if you have time? Thank you.

Comment: Kala you're trying to access the 7th item in the array, although there are only 6 items in the array.  The 6th index is the 7th item, which doesn't exist. 
 Arrays start from index 0.

Answer (score 1):

**The Selected answer will quickly hit a performance knock**.

True you need to implement the `getItemPosition()` method of your Adaptor but you should override it as intended.

The `getItemPosition()` method tells the ViewPager whether or not to delete viewItem, to redraw or not redraw viewItem when the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

Basically your implementation of `getItemPosition()` method is called to answer a simple question when `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is called.

The question is **"For each of the viewItems we have, has the position changed?"**

**There are two answers to this question**

1. `PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED //nothing changed save resources use cached viewitem`
2. `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE //we don't have that view any more recreate it or delete it.`

This question determines weather ViewPager recreates a new viewItem or uses one that was cached. Also it's from this answer that a decision is made to Remove a ViewItem deemed to be deleted or removed.

If ViewPager has to create a new viewitem for every data item in your items list every time `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. Imagine if you had a list of thousands of data from database; performance will be hit. That's exactly what just returning `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;` from `getItemPosition()` does. You are bypassing a crucial performance mechanism.

It's your responsibility as a developer to figure out how you answer that question. But remember the way you answer that question impacts performance of your app.

**How I implement it**

In Your **PagerAdapter**, `instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position)`. Set a tag on your view after instantiation. give it a unique name. I use the name of the image that I am showing in that view.

```
public MyAdaptorPagerAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<MyMedia> myMedias) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myMedias = myMedias;
    this.authCode = authCode;
}

public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    
    mageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    mageView.setTag(myMedia.getName()); //the most important part

    //....... do your stuff
    return imageView;
}
```

Then Override the `getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object)`

`super.getItemPosition(object);` in that message return answer no.1 above `PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED //nothing changed save resources use cached viewitem` that's the default behavior.

But we want to iterate through our data items to see if the viewItem passed to us as an object from `getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object)` still exists in out Adapter items array or not.

We are interested in when it does not exists. that's when we return answer no.2. `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE`

The viewItem passed to us as an Object, is exactly the Object we returned in our `public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position)` method. In my case it's the `ImageView`.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    int res = super.getItemPosition(object);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) object;
    final String tag = (String) imageView.getTag();

    // look for an item with our tag from our items list.
    MyMedia myMedia = null;
    for (MyMedia item : myMedias) {
        if (item.getName().equals(tag)) {
            myMedia = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if this item is null, then it does not exist in my items list
    // so I tell View pager I don't have that item.
    if (myMedia == null) {
        res = PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Last part. Now from your activity of fragment, just remove data from the Adapter array or ArrayList which you pass to your adapter as a data source.

```
//remove deleted item from myMedias ArrayList
myMedias.remove(position);

//tell your adapter instance data changed
pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```