# How can I save the state and value of button press between views in a viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Right now I have an Adapter class, which extends PagerAdapter. Inside I have my InstantiateItem() method.

Here I have instantiate several buttons on the view:

```
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

                final int delPosition = position;
                //Get the inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                //inflate the root layout
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection, null);

                //Grab instance of image
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.region);

                //Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
                imageView.setImageResource(regionImages.get(position));

                //scores toggle buttons
                zero = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_zero);
                one = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_one);
                two = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_two);
                three = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_three);
                four = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_four);
                five = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_five);
                six = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_six);
                seven = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_seven);
                eight = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_eight);
                nine = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_nine);
                ten = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_ten);

                one.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(1));
                two.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(2));
                three.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(3));
                four.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(4));
                five.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(5));
                six.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(6));
                seven.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(7));
                eight.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(8));
                nine.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(9));
                ten.setOnClickListener(createClickListener(10));

                //Back Arrow Button
                final ImageView back_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.back_nav_arrow);

                back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //it doesn't matter if you're already in the first item
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                });


                //forward button 
                final ImageView forward_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.forward_nav_arrow);

                forward_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //it doesn't matter if you're already in the last item
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    }
                });

                parent.addView(view, 0);
                return view;
            }
```

Here's the onClick action for the buttosn:

```
//onClickListener method that returns an interface
    private View.OnClickListener createClickListener(final int value) {
        return new View.OnClickListener()  {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                buttonValue = value;

                ToggleButton clickedButton = (ToggleButton) view;
                RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) clickedButton.getParent();

                for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    View nextChild = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (!(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (nextChild.getId() != clickedButton.getId() || !clickedButton.isChecked()) {
                        ToggleButton tb2 = (ToggleButton) nextChild;
                        tb2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
    }
```

I want to be able to save the state of the button press (right now it's like a radiobutton and when the user clicks on it, the button state is pressed down until they move to another button) and the buttonValue between the views in the viewpager.

Ultimately, I want a view at the end of my viewpager where I can list all the scores for each view as well as have the user go back to the other views and still have their button state pressed so that they can confirm it while swiping between views.

I am facing two problems right now:

1) Only the last buttonValue is saved and not all the buttonValues for all the views. How can I achieve saving all the scores in all the views and not just the last score in the last view?

2) Going from one view to another and back, the button state is still pressed. However, if I go to a third view from the last point, the button state pressed is no longer true. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is time to use fragment, although you can achieve what you want without it but using fragment gives a lot of benefits like saving your value when your activity is destroyed (rotation) or using the life cycle callback methods or reusing it to your future projects. anyway:

> 1) Only the last buttonValue is saved and not all the buttonValues for
>   all the views. How can I achieve saving all the scores in all the
>   views and not just the last score in the last view?

save the state of your button in anyway you like for example in sharedpreference, database or a list of custom object as a member of your activity or adapter something like below:

```
class MyToggleButton{
   boolean mState; // false = unpressed, true = pressed

}
```

and use `List<MyToggleButton>` to store them.

> 2) Going from one view to another and back, the button state is still
>   pressed. However, if I go to a third view from the last point, the
>   button state pressed is no longer true. How can I fix this?

you can use `List<MyToggleButton>` at `instantiateItem` to determine which button must have which state so you can set it correctly. when user change the state of any button you must update `MyToggleButton` state so that when ever you are going to look at `List<MyToggleButton>` find the correct one.

Comment: Is it possible to determine when the user can viewed all the views in the viewpager? Or not? Like if I wanted to enable a save button if all the views in the viewpager are viewed by the user?

Comment: Yes, for each page consider a variable called isViewed. you can set the variable to true at [onPageSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29)

Comment: Cool, that's a great idea. So, let me get this right: If I want to save the button state and value for each view, I would have to create a list and set the value of mState to true or false. I get the position of the view and map that to the state. So that I can do something like page 1 : button isPressed=true, page 2: button isPressed = false, etc.. So, when I'm switching between views, I can grab the value from that list when the view is newly launched and set the value of the button/state based on position.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it out now. I have a question I have my isViewed variable and I set it to true inside onPageSelected() but how do I know if the user viewed ALL pages? Do I do something like if(isViewed == true for ALL PAGES? What is ALL PAGES? Can I just assume that if the user lands on the last position, then they have viewed all pages?

Comment: "Can I just assume that if the user lands on the last position, then they have viewed all pages?" yes if you do not have any tabs. you can create an array of boolean variable corresponds to each page and use it like: `isViewed[page#2] = true`

Comment: Thanks. I have a question, I am getting null pointer exception when I set my save button visibility to invisible: http://pastebin.com/yNh6ZNp9. Am I setting the save button wrong?

Comment: No idea, debugge it step by step.

Comment: One more question, I have it set like this: http://pastebin.com/2zKt1v2W . So, now the save button is visible on the last page. But I want it so that it is visible on the last page and also on the previous pages if the user swipes back after viewing all the views. How can I best do that?

Comment: use a boolean variable as a flag. when user reaches last page set it to true. and on previous page you have to check this variable and if it is true show the button.

Comment: Good idea. I have it set up like that now with boolean but in code, how do I check previous page(s)?

Comment: you always check that boolean variable and if it is true you set the button visible, for just previous page you can do `if (position == numberOfPages.size()-2)`

Comment: I mean to say for previous pages. So I could have 10 pages. I set the save button to show on page 10 after user views all pages but when they go back, the save button must also show for all 10 pages. It's a dynamic number of pages though.

Comment: so first set that variable to false and check it on every page except last page, on last page set it to true. then when user goes back because it is now true, it can see the button.

Comment: I'm not getting how to find out the previous page positions and set isViewed = true in them. Can you give me an example?

Comment: you do not need to find out previous pages, If you can find out last page everything else is previous pages.So your code is something like: `if(isViewed){show button}else if(lastPage){isViewed = true}`

Comment: I have this but nothing new is happening to the previous views: if(isViewed)
                    {
                            save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                            System.out.println("Is this called? isViewed = true");


                    }else if (position == numberOfPages.size()-1) {

                            isViewed = true;
                            save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    }